# Laravel 5.4: Why isn't my page loading?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a laravel project under `www.mysite.com` and a second project under alias `www.mysite.com/portal`.

For my second project, my route isn't loading anything. When I go to `www.mysite.com/portal` i'm expecting to redirect to `www.mysite.com/portal/test` which is happening. I see the url change to `www.mysite.com/portal/test` but nothing is loading. This is what I see. Why is this happening? I can't figure out why i'm not seeing `Hello World`. Locally everything is working properly.

I did copy my `/vendor` from another project to this one. Don't know if that has anything to do with this issue.

[image]

I've tried all these commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:cache
```

These are my routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

   Route::get('/test',    ['as'=>'get_test',      'uses'=>'AccountController@test']);
   Route::get('/', function () { return \Redirect::route("get_test"); });

});
```

Controller

```
class AccountController extends Controller{

   public function test(Request $request){
       return "hello world";
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Comment: turn your "APP_DEBUG=true" on in your .env file for an actual error message

Comment: @ATechGuy i do have it on

Comment: Run this command `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log` and then refresh that page. Do you see any errors?

Comment: I think this is a server issue; you've got two Laravel projects, and the first one likely doesn't have a `/portal` route, so you're getting a 404 there, when it should be using the second project's routes, correct?

Comment: @prateekkathal i'm not seeing anything

Comment: i'm not sure how you have it on if your getting no error message. also check "APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug"

Comment: @ATechGuy I have that also, i updated my post containing my .env file

Comment: What is the thrown exception?

Comment: Only changes in `htaccess` file of your `public` directory can solve this problem.

Comment: @TimLewis That might be whats causing it. I didnt configure the server so not sure. Ill ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your first project's route is satisfying this term 
www.mysite.com/{param1}/{param2}.

**Two important points**

- when you are trying with www.mysite.com/portal/test here "portal" satisfying param1 and "test" satisfying param2 where you are running a query and after not getting any result you are redirecting to 404.
- your parent project's **.htaccess** file is not correctly configured for child project.

Please check your parent project's route files and .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

If your website is working then your route is not specify in your web route.

You need to write web route without any middleware like.

```
//routes/web.php
Route::get('/portal/test', 'AccountController@test');
```

after above modification try to access the url in your browser.